# Django: Abstract base class for managing db_table

Tags: python-3.x, django, metaclass

I'm trying to build my second django (and python for that matter, my first project being the django tutorial :)) project. since this is supposed to be something real i'd like to be thorough and build a good code structure before i go into the meat of the project.

I have a couple of simple models like this

```
class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    dueDate = models.DateTimeField()
```

I'm using PostgreSQL and i set up my models to use the app label as a database schema by defining the meta class of each model like this

```
class Meta:
    managed = True
    db_table = 'app_name\".\"modelname'
```

This works well. But i have to do this for every single model.

I want to keep it DRY though. So what i'm trying to do now is to have an abstract base class that does this automatically
so i tried the following:

```
class SchemaModel(models.Model):

    class Meta():
        abstract = True
        managed = True
        db_table = AppConfig.label+'\".\"'+self.__class__.lower()+'s'
```

(the base class was then inherited of course and i took the nested `Meta` class out of the normal models)

this didn't work though because `self` isn't accessible in `Meta`

after consulting the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) i tried this:

```
class SchemaModel(models.Model):

    class Meta():
        abstract = True
        managed = True
        db_table = '%(app_label)\".\"%(class)s'
```

which lead to the property `db_table` of every model being `"%(app_label)\".\"%(class)s"`

```
>>> t = Task()
>>> t._meta.db_table
'%(app_label)"."%(class)s'
>>>
```

I didn't find anything similar on the internet. Am i trying to do something impossible or "forbidden"?

## Solution

The solution is as shown in elyas answer to set the `db_table` property at the end of `models.py` by looping through all `__subclasses__()`

```
for model in SchemaModel.__subclasses__():
    db_table = '{}s'.format(model._meta.label_lower.replace('.','\".\"'))
    model._meta.original_attrs['db_table'] = db_table
    model._meta.db_table = db_table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say it's forbidden. But I can't think of any way to do this declaratively. There is *a way* to do it however.

Firstly, on your existing attempts:

#### Accessing 'self'

```py
db_table = AppConfig.label+'\".\"'+self.__class__.lower()+'s'
```

An instance object is never created from the `Meta` class when models are loaded, and so there is no `self` to reference. But even if an instance object were created, `db_table` is an [attribute of the class object](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects), so it is evaluated when the class object is created, which is before any instance object is created, so `self` cannot be accessed when defining a class attribute in this way.

**Edit:** And as you mentioned, the app_label cannot be accessed through `AppConfig.label`.

#### String formatting

```py
db_table = '%(app_label)\".\"%(class)s'
```

These placeholders are only used in a [very specific situation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name) when defining the `related_name` and `related_query_name` attributes of `ForeignKey` or `OneToOneField`'s fields in an abstract base class.

#### A solution

As I said, I can't think of any declarative way to achieve this. For example, trying to use `__qualname__` won't work because you would just end up with `SchemaModel.Meta` every time.

But you could put a for loop at the bottom of your models.py like this:

```py
for model in SchemaModel.__subclasses__():
    # Name your db_table here
    db_table = model._meta.app_label + '\".\"' + model._meta.model_name.lower() + 's'
    # Set db_table here
    model._meta.original_attrs['db_table'] = db_table
    model._meta.db_table = db_table
```

- All of `SchemaModel`'s children can be found using the built-in `__subclasses__()`  method.
- The `db_table` attribute needs to be updated in two places. Firstly in `_meta`, which is (partly) created by copying attributes from the `Meta` class, and secondly in `_meta.original_attrs` where the original `Meta` attributes are stored and are read by Django during migrations.

#### Alternative solution

Personally I would define the `db_table` names manually and simply have a unit test that checks that all models adhere to whatever naming convention I've come up. I prefer this so if another developer eyeballs a model they have never seen before they can get the full picture based on the declarations in the model (and the abstract base class) and don't get confused about an operation modifying them elsewhere.

Comment: thanks a lot for your in depth answer. as i said i'm very new :) when you say there is no way to do it declarative, then that means there is no way to keep these changes in django migrations right? in that case i think i'm just gonna do the alternative solution

Comment: You're welcome. When I say declarative I'm referring to the differences between declarative and imperative programming. Django does a lot of work behind the scenes so that we have the luxury of simply declaring what the model should look like. Using the for loop solution absolutely works in terms of migrations though - feel free to try it out and see what happens when you run `makemigrations`.

Comment: Nice it works perfectly. Although i didn't realize that i tried to reference `AppConfig.label` as a static property which obviously doesn't work. but i saw that i can get the complete name `'app_name.model_name'` from `Model._meta.label`. So i used that and just replaced the `'.'` by `'\".\"'`. I will put in my solution accordingly

Comment: Glad to hear it works! And yeah good point about `AppConfig.label`. I'll put a little edit in my answer so it doesn't catch anyone out :)