# Is there a way to dynamically select schema to execute SQL queries in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, orm, django-orm

I have a Django app which have a model that stores SQL queries that should be executed on another one of the multiple databases.

There is also a column called schema in that model which is used to store the schema where the query is to be executed.

```
class Query(BaseModel):
    STATUS_CHOICES = [
        ('active', 'Active'),
        ('inactive', 'Inactive'),
    ]

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    syntax = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    schema = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    database = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='active')
    extras = models.TextField()
```

How do I execute this raw SQL query stored in that model in the schema name that's stored in the same record.

There could be different sql queries with different schemas too.

Everytime the query is executed, it should dynamically take the schema from the record and run it in the database.

I know we can use the `.using()` in the ORM to specify the database to run the query on.

Is there any such similar thing to specify schema?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any such similar thing to specify schema? Not that I found.

SQL server fully qualified table names are in the format:

```
[database].[schema].[table]
```

So you could parse your SQL statements and ensure each table reference is preceded by the correct schema.

Alternatively, with preparation, ensure each schema has a user you could switch to.   switch to a user of the target schema, execute, then revert back.

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'user_otherschema';
SELECT * FROM mytable
REVERT
```

I am a novice on this subject. I constructed my response from this research:

[Django: Abstract base class for managing db_table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67218991/django-abstract-base-class-for-managing-db-table)

https://dev.to/koladev/sql-schema-in-django-models-37jp

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/sql/

[set default schema for a sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942023/set-default-schema-for-a-sql-query)

[EXECUTE AS USER = 'dbo' Throws error. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46054950/execute-as-user-dbo-throws-error-why)

[Parsing SQL with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394998/parsing-sql-with-python)